# How to convert a date in the form of a string with this format (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) to a DateTime object of this format (dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently using C# and I want to convert a string like "2022-01-15 18:40:30" to a DateTime object with this format "15-01-2022 18:40:30". Below is what I've tried.

```
string stringDate = "2022-01-15 18:40:30";
string newStringDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

DateTime newDateFormat = DateTime.ParseExact(newStringDate, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But the result i keep getting is "2022-01-15T18:40:30"

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: a `DateTime` object is the _binary representation_ and does not _have_ a format. a _string,_ which you can convert a datetime into, has a format, which you can specify - [See Also The Manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-6.0#system-datetime-tostring(system-string))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others pointed out, you have a internal data value for DateTime.

So, FOR SURE we suggest that you convert the string into that internal format.

Once you do that, then you are free to output that internal date time value to ANY kind of format and output you want.

Thus, we have this:

```
        string stringDate = "2022-01-15 18:40:30";
        DateTime MyDate = DateTime.ParseExact(stringDate,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        // now we can output convert to anything we want.
        Debug.Print("Day of week = " + MyDate.ToString("dddd"));
        Debug.Print("Month = " + MyDate.ToString("MM"));
        Debug.Print("Month (as text) = " + MyDate.ToString("MMMM"));

        // desired format
        Debug.Print(MyDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

And output is this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The DateTime object by itself does not have a specific "format".

The string representation gets created when you call the .ToString() function.

There are multiple [overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-6.0#overloads) of the ToString function with which you can specify the format.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime("2022-01-15");
        DateTime time = Convert.ToDateTime("18:40:30");

        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date.ToShortDateString() + " " + time.ToShortTimeString());
```

try this style

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
string stringDate = "2022-01-15 18:40:30";
Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Parse(stringDate)).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: Yes, this would return a string with the desired format, however what I'm trying to get is a DateTime type variable with that format.

Comment: DateTime object does not have a format and just stores the data. We specify the format when we want to generate an output.